# In Unity C# deactivates a gameObjects collider upon collision, reactivating that collider but now the collision code is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in Unity using C# I'm writing code for a gameObject that upon collision with a player projectile deactivates the objects collider which is on a separate child object. Then on a timer delay reactivates the gameObjects collider this all works however when I try to fire the projectile at the object again the collision code to destroy the object no longer works and I do not know why.

Here is the code I tried so far:

Here is the code for the object I want the collider to be deactivated of:

```
    public GameObject blockCollider;
    public bool blockDestroyed = false;
    float respawnTimer = 0f;
    public float timeToRes = 2f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Timer for how long to respawn
        if (blockDestroyed == true)
        {
            blockCollider.SetActive(false);
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            Debug.Log("Timer activated");
            respawnTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log(respawnTimer);

            if (respawnTimer >= timeToRes)
            {
                Debug.Log("Begin Respawn");
                Respawn();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Respawn()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
        blockCollider.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("block respawned");
        blockDestroyed = false;
    }
```

Here is the code of the child object which contains the collider and the collision code:

```
    public BreakableBlock bBlock;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        GameObject whatCol = other.gameObject;
        if (whatCol.CompareTag("Projectile"))
        {
           
            bBlock.blockDestroyed = true;
            Debug.Log("Block Hit");
          
        }
    }
```

Here is the code of the player projectile:

```
    Rigidbody2D rB;
    public float bulletSpeed = 10f;
    public float damage = -2.5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Vector2 force = transform.right * bulletSpeed;
        rB.AddForce(force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to reset the timer after respawning *(or on collision)*

```
public void Respawn()
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
    blockCollider.SetActive(true);
    Debug.Log("block respawned");
    blockDestroyed = false;
    respawnTimer = 0f; // Reset the timer for the next destruction.
}
```

---

Also, in your `update`, you do not have to constantly re-disable the gameobject/collider, you just have to do it once on collision:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    GameObject whatCol = other.gameObject;
    if (whatCol.CompareTag("Projectile"))
    {
        // Disable it once here, and it will remain disabled
        // Until you re-enable it again.
        bBlock.blockDestroyed = true;
        bBlock.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
        bBlock.gameObject.setActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Block Hit");
        // Ideally, you should do a function call to `bBlock`
        // that notifies that it has collided with a bullet,
        // to let it disable itself.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot I spend a couple hours trying to figure this out myself but your answer fixed it and it is now working as intended.